# How can I replace in my .emacs all these `require` with `package.el` and `MELPA`?

Tags: package-repositories, require

My `.emacs` still uses old-style (pre MELPA, pre package.el) initializations.

**Current (this works)**

I'll use `web-mode` as a concrete example.

If I manually download `web-mode.el` and put it in `~/elisp`, then start Emacs (25) with the `.emacs` file

```
(package-initialize)  ; Irrelevant here. Added by Emacs.
(setq load-path
      (cons "~/elisp" load-path))

(require 'web-mode)

(set-face-attribute 'web-mode-css-at-rule-face nil :foreground "magenta red")
```

all is well.

I'd like to change this `.emacs` to be able to use any machine+account without having to install manually an `~/elisp` on each machine/account.

**MELPA + package.el attempt (this doesn't work)**

My attempt is:

```
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("MELPA Stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)

(custom-set-variables
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (web-mode))))

(set-face-attribute 'web-mode-css-at-rule-face nil :foreground "magenta red")
```

but this fails with

```
error: Invalid face, web-mode-css-at-rule-face
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

When I run `package-list-packages` I see

[image: web-mode: installed[1]]

and so it appears that web-mode is installed.

I now have the impression from phil's comment that using package.el + MELPA may not actually spare me from having to download and install elisp packages manually. Please confirm one way or the other.

**Post answer**

It turns out that this change cannot be completely made. Too many packages are not on MELPA.

Comment: MELPA is a package archive and `package.el` a package manager, `package-selected-packages` can therefore not be a MELPA-specific thing.

Comment: Package `web-mode` was not loaded. Did you do `(package-initialize)`? It sounds like you have "installed" it but not loaded it.

Comment: @Drew Rewrote the question. Could you look again?

Comment: Try putting `package-initalize` after your setting of `package-selected-packages`. The former activates autoloads provided by packages. If you don't tell it to choose package `web-mode` until after you tell it to activate the autoloads of installed packages, then perhaps that is your problem. Dunno.

Comment: @Drew Thanks, but that didn't help. Still the same error message.

Comment: Have you actually `package-install`'d `web-mode` from MELPA?

Comment: @phils I updated the question. Does the line/image "web-mode 15 installed" confirm that I have indeed installed web-mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but I strongly suspect that what you need to do is:

```el
(eval-after-load "web-mode"
  '(set-face-attribute 'web-mode-css-at-rule-face nil :foreground "magenta red"))
```

The `web-mode` package is evidentially installed, but it is not yet loaded, and so you were trying to use a face that is yet to be defined.